# Stumped with Angular module inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement John Papa's Angular architecture, but I can't seem to get it to work. I feel like I'm missing something basic about how inheritance works.

I'm just trying to access a factory method =, test.ping, that lives in the base app module, from the feature module, foo.module.js. When I try to call the function, I get an error in the console:
    ReferenceError: 'test' is undefined

```
//app.js
(function () {

angular.module("app", ['app.foo'])
    .factory('test', [function () {

        var service = {
            ping: ping
        };
        return service
        function ping() {
            alert('PING Service method called.');
        }
    }])
})();

//foo.module.js
(function () {

angular.module('app.foo', []);

})();

//foo.js
(function () {

angular
    .module('app.foo')
    .controller('Foo', Foo);

Foo.$inject = [];

function Foo() {
    var vm = this;
    alert('Foo loaded'); //the alert is working

    vm.ping = function () {
        alert('Ping button clicked.'); //the alert is working
        test.ping(); //this throws console error
    }
}
})();

//html
<body data-ng-controller="Foo as fooCtrl">
    <button data-ng-click="fooCtrl.ping()">PING</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `test` service in dependency injection.

```
Foo.$inject = [];
```

change this to

```
Foo.$inject = ['test'];
```

And also

```
function Foo() {
```

this to

```
function Foo(test) {
```

Comment: That was it! Makes sense... just like having to add angular $ services that you want to use. I knew it was something simple... got lost in all the layers, but will be worth it once everything is wired up and working.